# como actualizar campos de cantidad?

Tags: javascript, php

tengo una tabla creada con datos sql dentro del while de los productos hay in ipmput de cantidad del productos y tiene la propiedad onclick una función Registrar() lo que pasa es que si yo mando el id por pos me manda solo el primer id de la tabla pero si lo pongo dentro de la función onclick="Registrar(    );"  ahi si manda el id que debería ahora el problema esta con el campo de la cantidad que no encuentro forma de mandarlo
este es el código`

```js
function Registrar(cedula) {
    cadena = "cedula=" + cedula;
    $("#respuesta").html(" Por favor espera un momento ");
    alert(cedula);
    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'html',
        url: "registro.php",
        data: cadena,
        success: function(resp) {
            $('#respuesta').html(resp);
            Limpiar();
            Cargar();
        }
    });
}
```

```html
 <script src="ajax.js"></script>
 <table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Nº Descargo</th>
<th>Fecha de Descargos</th>

</tr>
</thead>
<?php
    while($row = $con->arreglo($consulta)) 
    { 
?>

<tr >

<input  id="cedula" name="cedula"   type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row["cedula"]; ?>">
<td><?php echo $row["nombre"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["cedula"]; ?></td>
<td><input   id="cantidad" name="cantidad" class="form-control" style="height:36px;"  /></td>
<td><button onclick="Registrar( <?php echo  $row['cedula']; ?> );" tabindex="7">Guardar </td>
</tr>
<?php 
    }   


?>
</table>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

No es la mejor solución pero podría funcionar si la cedula es unica para cada producto

```
function Registrar(cedula) {
    cadena = "cedula=" + cedula;
    cantidad = $('#'+ cedula).val();
    $("#respuesta").html(" Por favor espera un momento ");
    alert(cedula);
    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'html',
        url: "registro.php",
        data: {Cadena:cadena, Cantidad: cantidad}
        success: function(resp) {
            $('#respuesta').html(resp);
            Limpiar();
            Cargar();
        }
    });
}
 <script src="ajax.js"></script>
 <table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Nº Descargo</th>
<th>Fecha de Descargos</th>

</tr>
</thead>
<?php
    while($row = $con->arreglo($consulta)) 
    { 
?>

<tr >

<input  id="cedula" name="cedula"   type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row["cedula"]; ?>">
<td><?php echo $row["nombre"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["cedula"]; ?></td>
<td><input   id="<?php echo $row["cedula"]; ?>" name="cantidad" class="form-control" style="height:36px;"  /></td>
<td><button onclick="Registrar( <?php echo  $row['cedula']; ?> );" tabindex="7">Guardar </td>
</tr>
<?php 
    }   


?>
</table>
```